# Bypass volume potentiometer

Tags: potentiometer, bypass, volume

Can't get my headphones replaced in warranty during COVID lockdown so I am forced to fix the old ones.

I have a pair of old headsets that have this volume potentiometer that I would like to bypass entirely, and keep the volume full at all times.

Could anyone tell me which pins I would need to manipulate?
I have numbered the pins and shown which direction the potentiometer goes for volume increase.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a multimeter so you can verify things? The board has markings like L-I, L-O, R-I and R-O. I'd be surprised if those do not mean left/right and in/out. I strongly believe the green wires (3,4) soldered together bypasses the other channel, and the other channel is pins 5&2. But it is not known if the potentiometer is in series or shunting to ground, so perhaps remove the potentiometer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The Ls are left channel and coloured green.
- The Rs are right channel and coloured red.
- The shield, GND, is copper.
- The mic is red and has its own copper sheild.

Lift L-C and connect it to L-I. Lift R-C an connect it to R-I.

All instructions are without warranty!

Comment: Worked. This would cause any problems in the future? Or any damage to the onboard DAC/amp on my laptop?

Comment: No. You've just connected what would would be connected if the volume control was at max. The speakers are connected to the pot wipers and the amplifier input is connected to the "top" tags on on the pot. When you turn to max volume you connect the wires together as you have done permanently.