# Bypass broken potentiometer in headphone

Tags: pcb, audio, headphones

My headphone's volume control is broken so I am getting audio only on the left speaker. I have ordered a replacement but it's going to take a few days to arrive.  Seeing [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/491695/bypass-volume-potentiometer) question, I had some hope, but I'd rather ask for some advice before trying anything myself.

Should I join the red/blue wire on the left to the ones on the right?

[image]

[image: The PCB for the volume controller]

Comment: isn't the red/blue wire connected to a pad that is labeled `Vcc`?

Comment: No that's the red/green one

Comment: Impossible to say for sure.  But you can easily figure it out.   Use a metal tweezer and short-out from Pin 1-2.  If that doesn't make it full volume, try shorting from 2-3.   One of those will work.  It won't be pin 1-3.    Then do same on the other side.  (full experiment, don't assume both sides work the same)

Comment: are these battery powered headphones? Otherwise I don't see why there would be a Vcc

Comment: They have Led lights

Comment: @KyleB Thanks man, that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was to join the +ve wires to the endpoint. Thank you [Kyle B](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/249644/kyle-b) for the suggestion.

[image]

Comment: NP!   Glad it did